# Login Yahoo with cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to login yahoo with curl. here is sample class i used.

```
<?php

class Yahoo
{
    public $cookies = 'cookies.txt';
    private $user = null;
    private $pass = null;

    /*Data generated from cURL*/
    public $content = null;
    public $response = null;

    /* Links */
    private $url = array(
                        'login'     => 'http://smallbusiness.yahoo.com/dashboard/mybusinesses?brand=local',
                        'submit'    => 'https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?'
                        );

    /* Fields */
    public $data = array();

    public function __construct ($user, $pass)
    {

        $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pass;        

    }

    public function login()
    {

                $this->cURL($this->url['login']);
                if($form = $this->getFormFields($this->content, 'fsLogin'))
                {
                    //echo "<pre>".print_r($form,true);exit;
                    $form['login']= $this->user;
                    $form['passwd'] = md5(md5($this->pass).$form['.challenge']);
                    $form['passwd_raw'] = $this->pass;
                    $form[".md5"] = 1;
                    $form[".hash"] = 1;
                    $form[".js"] = 1;
                    //echo "<pre>".print_r($form,true);exit;
                    $this->cURL($this->url['submit'], $form);
                    echo $this->content;exit;
                }
               echo $this->content;exit;    
        }
    }

    /* Scan for form */
    private function getFormFields($data, $id)
    {
        if($id =! 'fsLogin'){
            //echo "aw";
            if (preg_match('/(<form.*?id=.?'.$id.'.*?<\/form>)/is', $data, $matches)) {
                $inputs = $this->getInputs($matches[1]);

                return $inputs;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            $data = preg_replace('/<script.*?<\/script>/is','', $data);
            $data = preg_replace('/<style.*?<\/style>/is','', $data);
            $data = preg_replace('/<!--.*?-->/is', '', $data);
            $data = preg_replace('/<!\[.*?\]>/is','', $data);
            $data = preg_replace('/<noscript.*?<\/noscript>/is','', $data);

            if (preg_match_all('/<fieldset.*>(.*)?<\/fieldset>/is', $data, $matches)) {
                $inputs = $this->getInputs($matches[0][0]);


                return $inputs;
            } else {

                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Get Inputs in form */
    private function getInputs($form)
    {
        $inputs = array();

        $elements = preg_match_all('/(<input[^>]+>)/is', $form, $matches);

        if ($elements > 0) {
            for($i = 0; $i < $elements; $i++) {
                $el = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $matches[1][$i]);

                if (preg_match('/name=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $name)) {
                    $name  = $name[1];
                    $value = '';

                    if (preg_match('/value=(?:["\'])?([^"\']*)/i', $el, $value)) {
                        $value = $value[1];
                    }

                    $inputs[$name] = $value;
                }
            }
        }

        return $inputs;
    }

    /* Perform curl function to specific URL provided */
    public function cURL($url, $post = false)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookies);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookies);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);

        if($post)   //if post is needed
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
        }

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        $this->content = curl_exec($ch);
        $this->response = curl_getinfo( $ch );
        $this->url['last_url'] = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
        curl_close($ch);
    }
}
?>
```

I somehow manage to reach in login form and get all the fields that are placed in the login form. but when i tried to post it $this->url['submit'] i only see the login form instead of a page with a list of business listing. any idea how to make this work?

Comment: why don't you use Oauth API

Comment: cant, i am creating a script that update business details in profile providers. ex. yahoo, facebook, twitter.. etc. so i need to run this just by scraping the page.

Comment: I dont think any site would allow to post from another domain

Comment: i have tried twitter, yellowpage, foursquare, facebook. and i successfully updated my listing just by scraping the page.

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this? I'm doing the same in C# and am getting the Login form again in response to submitting.